# Best way to simply ask "how often do you"

Tags: conversational

Seems like a very simple question, but Im not sure of the best way to ask this conversationally.My understanding is if your asking over a specific period like a week or month, and taking "buy that" as an example its good to say 月かんかい買う？１週間なんかい買う？

But without that period marker what would be a natural way to ask, how often do you buy that? my guess yesterday in conversation was それは何頻度で買うの？
But it seemed pretty unclear to the native speaker 相手.

Comment: I can read Japanese much better than speak it.  Having said that there are a variety of phrases you could use: どのくらい、いくど、いくたび... I have a feeling that the later two may be more literary and so since I'm a poor judge of the differences between spoken and written Japanese, I'll leave this as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: `月かんかい買う` You meant to type 月**な**んかい買う, right?

Answer (score 1):

> "how often do you" -- the best way to ask this conversationally.   if
>   your asking over a specific period like a week or month, and taking
>   "buy that" as an example its good to say 月かんかい買う？１週間なんかい買う？   But
>   without that period marker what would be a natural way to ask, how
>   often do you buy that? my guess yesterday in conversation was
>   それは何頻度で買うの？ But it seemed pretty unclear to the native speaker 相手.

mm.. Maybe we start it by asking それ、よく買うの？, still sounding pretty direct though, a little attenuated than どのくらいの頻度（ひんど）で買うの？

I think if I have a need to ask that, I'd rather directly ask それ、週にどのくらい買う？, and this can mean either the amount or the frequency.

Comment: yeah in that specific conversation it eas intended to be quite direct and specific, although in more casual conversation よく買うの sounds much better.